# Custom parameter in Authorization c#

Tags: c#, authentication, authorization, custom-authentication

I have a problem, I need to do something like this in order to protect my API based on permission code.
Into the "OnAuthorization" i check the jwtToken, db and soon.

```
[AuthorizePermissionByCode("fr")]
[HttpGet]
public int Get()
{
    DO STUFF
}
```

I have write a class in order to manage AuthorizePermissionByCode

```
namespace CustomAuthorizeAttribute
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class AuthorizePermissionByCode : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public string Permissions { get; set; } //Permission string to get from controller
        
        

        public AuthorizePermissionByCode(string Permissions)
        {
            this.Permissions = Permissions;
        }


        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            
                filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
}
```

I have no error, build success and soon, but never enter into "OnAuthorization".
I need to edit in some way my startup?
I put:

```
services.AddAuthentication();

services.AddAuthorization();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not particularly sure of your intentions but i haven done something close in time pass.

Take a look at this code and refactor where appropriate.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/56fb14/custom-authorization-in-mvc/